# Strictly or Increasing function..

Tags: functions

[https://www.aplustopper.com/function-increasing-decreasing/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKzKs.png)

Hi , i was recently learning about strictly increasing and decreasing functions in school, and my teacher told that the graph that i attaches is increasing and not strictly increasing...But if we see the defination of strictly increasing , it says that slope should be always positive , and this satisfies that...so why is it not strictly increasing

Comment: He is wrong. The definition is that $f(a)>f(b)$ for all $a>b$ for a function $f$ to be strictly increasing. Exactly that is the case here, so this function is strictly increasing

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the bit in the middle is "supposed" to be horizontal, and it's just been drawn badly. If the bit in the middle *is* horizontal, then yes, it is an increasing function but not a strictly increasing one.

As it is, the graph you have shown us *is* strictly increasing, most definitely.